# Was Meister Eder insane?

Tags: meister-eder-und-sein-pumuckl

In the long-running *Pumuckl* franchise (which has close resemblances of the story of Pinocchio), Meister Eder is the only person who can see, talk to and generally interact with Pumuckl:

[image: Pumuckl chilling in a hammock]

The chaotic kobold (some sort of "friendly" goblin) is known to lay havoc in his path. He is also often responsible for getting Meister Eder into all sorts of predicaments, due to his careless and childish nature.

Pumuckl is never seen to be actually evil, but he could be interpreted to be Meister Eder's suppressed subconsciousness ("[id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Id)"), doing things that Meister Eder's consciousness ("[super-ego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Super-ego)") wouldn't allow him to do.

Seeing a kobold that nobody else sees, and blaming him for the (seemingly) bad things that happen to him, I would characterise as schizophrenia or at least some other sort of mental instability.

It's been some time since I actually watched the show (and I didn't watch it regularly, by very far); are there hints, that Pumuckl is a reflection of Meister Eder's own personality channelling a suppressed part of him?

Answer (score 3):

This certainly isn't the answer you're looking for, but any "evidence" of the mischievous little kobold being the id of Meister Eder is likely coincidental.

There a several recurring themes in *Pumuckl*, and while some of them may be mistaken for the secret instincts of the carpenter, this certainly isn't the general case.

For example, a common occurrence is of a customer discovering a belonging of Pumuckl and desiring to purchase it. While this doesn't prove that he isn't simply an insane old man, it doesn't help the cause either. If this tiny furniture was produced as a result of his insanity, then he would have no issues selling it to whoever wants it, as his desire for money should outweigh the feeling of loss of some miniature chair.

Additionally, a great number of episodes center around Pumuckl sneaking out of the hose and spying on the neighbors and playing pranks. These are things that occur while Meister Eder is away from Pumuckl, so again, while it *could* work, it doesn't really jive.

He often punishes Pumuckl for his behavior, for example, denying him desert while he eats it himself. This doesn't really work with him being a manifestation of his desires/mind. Further, Pumuckl is not always mischievous. He is also known to try and help Eder through disagreements with his various relations. This desire for reconciliation does not fit well with being a specific part of Eder's mind.

Again, while this doesn't explain anything, the legend of the kobold is such that when one is captured (by carpentry glue in this case), the kobold is then visible to the person who captured him (the carpenter).

While one could take any example and say how that particular instance works for Pumuckl being a mental manifestation, the various examples don't quite work together.

Comment: I disagree with your observation; If Eder built that chair in accordance with his insanity, then selling it would make his fantasy world buckle, something he would avoid at all cost. Secondly, denying Pumuckl desert and eating it himself, fits perfectly. If the super-ego tries to reprimand his id, this would be the perfect way to do so (it's almost allegorical; eating desert being a pure indulgence, lacking any logical reason).

Comment: While there are no "rules" governing this, mental manifestations and allegorical devices don't typically buckle to governing forces. For example, if the Meister was in control, Pumuckl shouldn't really exist, but if he is not in control, Pumuckl should be the one eating the desert while the Meister would be left somewhat unhappily moderated by self control. If Pumuckl was a mental manifestation, having the Meister eat the pudding that Pumuckl so desired makes little sense. It'd be like saying you won't give in to your chocolate craving, but instead you'd enjoy the chocolate intellectually.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: The thing is, someone with a mental...arrr...'problem' like that has a very warped perception. What seems totally ridiculous and stupid to the outside world might be totally normal to that person. Making something to eat, eating it afterwards and claiming that the illusion ate it might seem stupid, but somebody who does believe that that little guy ate it, will believe that.

Comment: But the exact circumstances of that might be better [asked on Cognitive Science](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bobby I think you may have mixed up the described situation. In the example discussed the real person ate some sweets and deprived the "magical creature" of the indulgence.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, childhood memories... It's been quite a while (more than 20 years), but from what I remember, your suggestion sounds interesting from a perspective watching the series as an adult. However - as mentioned in Gorchestopher's answer - there are several things simply happening outside of Eder's range.

Also, it's not simply "he's invisible to everyone else". It's established during the first (or first few?) episodes:

- **According to Pumuckl, kobolds are invisible to humans, unless caught by them before** (this seems to be inspired by the kobolds of irish/celtic origin; think he's been talking about the Big Book of Kobolds or something defining that). During the first episode, Pumuckl sneaks through Eder's workshop, finally getting caught in glue and later on freed by Eder.
- I might be wrong here - cause it's simply been too long - but I think I remember the fact, that **animals were able to see kobolds all the time**. I think I remember at least one episode, where he's followed by a neighbour's cat and there might have been an episode where he rode a mouse.
- Another one where I might be wrong, but I think I remember later episodes introducing a kid being able to see him as well. Plus there's been at least one movie as well (never seen it), that - as far as I remember - doesn't include Eder at all. So that would either be coincidence, non-canon or whatever.

Regarding "incidents" with customers I'd like to add, that there have been occassions where Eder actually sold something (or wanted to sell something) belonging to (or being wanted by) Pumuckl, causing him to somehow try to disrupt the purchase (biting, dropping tools, etc.). And let's be honest, that's something that won't work considering Pumuckl not being "real". The customers would notice Eder doing something, but they actually never notice what really happens or how/why. The whole "being insane" approach works while he's alone, but once his environment (i.e. other people) are involved, it simply no longer works or is no longer that believable.

Comment: As per this episode guide Pumuckl did indeed stick to a chewing gum and becomes visible to the owner of said gum: https://www.fernsehserien.de/meister-eder-und-sein-pumuckl/folgen/1x08-pumuckl-und-die-schule-1765. (And once again one ancient question that somehow floated up to the top of the tile. I sometimes hat stackexchange).